# Обратная связь двух input на Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать обратную связь двух `input` на `Jquery`?
Пока получается только от `#element1` к `#element2`:

```js
 $('#element1').keyup(function() {
   var data = $('#element1').val();
   $('#element2').val(data);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="element1">
<input type="text" id="element2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#element1').keyup(function() {
  var data = $('#element1').val();
  $('#element2').val(data);
});
$('#element2').keyup(function() {
  var data = $('#element2').val();
  $('#element1').val(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="element1">
<input type="text" id="element2">
```